# Sending function keys (F1-F12) over SSH

Tags: ssh, terminal, android

I have a Fedora machine that I can SSH to. One of the programs I'd like to use occasionally uses the function keys. The problem is that I'm SSH'ing from an Android tablet (ASUS Transformer Infinity) with a physical keyboard, but no <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys. So, until the terminal app I'm using (VX ConnectBot) decides to add them as a feature, I'm looking for a way to send them using the rest of the keyboard.

I can use all printable ASCII characters, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: I think you'd be better off asking on Android.SE.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Terminals only understand characters, not keys. So al function keys are encoded as sequences of characters, using control characters. Apart from a few common ones that have an associated control character (<kbd>Tab</kbd> is `Ctrl+I`, <kbd>Enter</kbd> is `Ctrl+M`, <kbd>Esc</kbd> is `Ctrl+[`), function keys send escape sequences, beginning with `Ctrl+[ [` or `Ctrl+[ O`. You can use the [`tput`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tput) command to see what escape sequence applications expect for each function key on your terminal. These sequences are stored in the [`terminfo`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/terminfo) database. For example, the shell snippet below shows the escape sequences corresponding to each function key.

```
$ for x in {1..12}; do echo -n "F$x "; tput kf$x | cat -A; echo; done
F1 ^[OP
F2 ^[OQ
F3 ^[OR
F4 ^[OS
F5 ^[[15~
F6 ^[[17~
F7 ^[[18~
F8 ^[[19~
F9 ^[[20~
F10 ^[[21~
F11 ^[[23~
F12 ^[[24~
```

Another way to see the escape sequence for a function key is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in a terminal application that doesn't rebind the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> key (such as the shell). <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> inserts the next character (which will be the escape character) literally, and you'll be able to see the rest of the sequence, which consists of ordinary characters.

Since the sequences may be awkward to type, do investigate changing the key bindings in your application or using another terminal emulator. Also, note that you may have a time limit: some applications only recognize escape sequences if they come in fast enough, so that they can give a meaning to the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key alone.

Comment: How do I add shifted function keys to the list your command provides?

Comment: @drevicko On xterm, Shift+F1 is `kf13`, Shift+F2 is `kf14`, etc. Then Ctrl+F1 is `kf25`, Ctrl+Shift+F1 is `kf37`, Alt+F1 is `kf49`. I don't know if this works on other terminals nor what you get if you have an actual F13 key.

Answer (score 3):

Android Terminal Emulator by Jack Palevich uses key combinations with the volume keys to send a variety of keys, including function keys. There is also Hacker's Keyboard which has every key available that a real keyboard would have.

Comment: Thanks, the Hacker Keyboard should cover what I need for now.

Answer (score 2):

As Drake Clarris suggests, on Android, you can install alternate keyboards, such as [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) that include F-keys.

However, if for whatever reason you can't install a new keyboard, there are other alternatives, as long as your terminal app allows you to press `Esc` and/or `Alt`.

You can often use `Esc` followed by `Number`, or `Alt+Number` to simulate `F1`-`F10`, using `0` for `F10`.

These shortcuts are very helpful when using a terminal emulator on a phone or other restricted device that lacks physical F-keys. They are also useful with a physical keyboard when your terminal program or another program running in the same session (eg byobu/screen/tmux) intercepts F-keys for its own purposes.

- Example with `Esc`: I want to press `F10` to quit `mc`, the Midnight Commander, but Gnome Terminal intercepts `F10` and interprets it as its menu key. Instead, I press `Esc`, then `0`. Gnome Terminal passes the inputs separately, `mc` interprets them as `F10`, and `mc` exits.
- Example with `Alt`: I want to press `F4` to filter `htop`, but `byobu` intercepts `F4` and interprets it as "next window". Instead, I hold `Alt` and press `4`. Byobu passes the key combination through, `htop` interprets it as `F4`, and enables filtering.

The `Alt` method may not work if an application interprets `Alt+Number` as a distinct key combination from `F-Number`. I have not encountered this problem in practice.

I don't know if there's a way to type `F11` or `F12` this way, as I've never needed to.