# Escape sequences for function keys (F1-F12), especially F11 and F12

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, gnu-screen, byobu

I want to use the terminal multiplexer `byobu`, so I need to use the function keys (<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>).  However, I am accessing a remote machine via SSH, so I need to send function keys over SSH.  (I'm running Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS.)

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53589/9605) to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53581/sending-function-keys-f1-f12-over-ssh) explains that "Terminals only understand characters, not keys," so I need to use escape sequences to send function keys over SSH.  But I'm not sure what are the control characters for <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> on my particular platform.  So, I used the command suggested in [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53589/9605):

```
for x in {1..12}; do echo -n "F$x "; tput kf$x | cat -A; echo; done
```

I get this output:

```
F1 ^[OP
F2 ^[OQ
F3 ^[OR
F4 ^[OS
F5 ^[Ot
F6 ^[Ou
F7 ^[Ov
F8 ^[Ol
F9 ^[Ow
F10 ^[Ox
F11 
F12
```

This says -- or so it would seem -- that <kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> have no escape sequences associated with them.  Have they been stolen by another program, and if so, how can I get them back?

Answer (score 4):

`tput` tells you what the terminal advertises as its function keys. Terminals often don't advertise all the function keys and keychords that they support. To see what escape sequences the terminal actually sends, use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> method mentioned in [that same answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53581/sending-function-keys-f1-f12-over-ssh/53589#53589): press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in a terminal application that doesn't rebind the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> key (such as the shell). <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> inserts the next character (which will be the escape character) literally, and you'll be able to see the rest of the sequence, which consists of ordinary characters.

If Byobu doesn't detect your terminal's escape sequences correctly, copy the corresponding definitions from `/usr/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.screen` to `~/.byobu/.screenrc` and modify the escape sequences to match your terminal. For example, if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>F12</kbd> inserts `^[[24~`, add

```
bindkey "^[[24~" process x
```

Comment: Thanks. What does the `x` stand for?

Comment: @Andrew Register `x`, which is set to the escape sequence at the top of `f-keys.screen`. Thus binding a key to `process x` effectively makes that key a prefix for screen commands.

Comment: By any chance, do you have time to chat for a minute? I'm having difficulty knowing what to do.

Comment: @Andrew I do now. Even if I'm not around, there's often someone in the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux).